# .htaccess, cannot get first part of a URL in rewrite condition

Tags: .htaccess

I am attempting to get the following results with an .htaccess file.

```
URL:                      Behavior(rewrite to):
example.com/x/            view-test.php?page=x
example.com/x/y           view-test.php?page=y&parent=x
example.com/x/y/z         view-test.php?page=z&parent=y&grandparent=z
```

I have the following .htaccess rules, which also include some folders which needs to ignore this scheme:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/(admin|images|scripts|css|fonts|view-test\.php)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]+)/?$ /view-test.php?grandparent=$1&parent=$2&page=$3  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/(admin|images|scripts|css|fonts|view-test\.php)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]+)/?$ /view-test.php?&parent=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/(admin|images|scripts|css|fonts|view-test\.php)/ [NC]
#RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ /view-test.php?page=$1 [L]
```

however, whenever I uncomment the last two lines I get an internal server error. the parent/page and grandparent/parent/page structures work fine. How can I re-write this last rule (and the preceding rules if nessecary) to achieve the desired result for the first pattern (just a page)?

Comment: Have you thought of splitting the path with PHP? That would be much easier.

Comment: Where does the OIE folder come into play? Where is the htaccess located (root or in OIE)?

Comment: @Gerben whoops, that part of some testing i was doing, and shouldn't be in the question the way it was written out. I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin|images|scripts|css|fonts|view-test\.php)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,S=3]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ view-test.php?grandparent=$1&parent=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ view-test.php?&parent=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ view-test.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Problem was that you were missing trailing slash `/` in in your last RewriteRule condition.

Comment: I've tried that, and yet it still throws server errors when I try that.

Comment: I have made some corrections in my answer, can you pls try again. Moreover if you still get server error then do provide matching error.log lines here.

Answer (score 0):

```
# remove slash at the end to prevent redirect loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(OIE|admin|images|scripts|css|fonts|view-test\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]+)/?$ /OIE/view-test.php?grandparent=$1&parent=$2&page=$3  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/(admin|images|scripts|css|fonts|view-test\.php)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]+)/?$ /OIE/view-test.php?&parent=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/(admin|images|scripts|css|fonts|view-test\.php)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ /OIE/view-test.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ view-test.php?page=$1

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ view-test.php?page=$1&parent=$2

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ view-test.php?page=$1&parent=$2&grandparent=$3
```